# How to convert string to number based on units

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, case

I am trying to change the following strings into their respective numerical values, by identifying the units (millions or billions) and then multiplying accordingly. I believe I am having issues with the variable types but can't seem to find a solution. Any tips?

> `1.44B` to `1,440,000,000`
>
> `1.564M` to `1,564,000`

```
UPDATE [_ParsedXML_Key_Stats]  
SET     [Value] =  CASE

WHEN right(rtrim([_ParsedXML_Key_Stats].[Value]),1) = 'B' And [_ParsedXML_Key_Stats].[NodeName] = 'EBITDA'
THEN substring(rtrim([_ParsedXML_Key_Stats].[Value]),1,len([_ParsedXML_Key_Stats].[Value])-1) * 1000000000
        
WHEN right(rtrim([_ParsedXML_Key_Stats].[Value]),1) = 'M' And [_ParsedXML_Key_Stats].[NodeName] = 'EBITDA'
THEN substring(rtrim([_ParsedXML_Key_Stats].[Value]),1,len([_ParsedXML_Key_Stats].[Value])-1) * 1000000                        
ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: What database are you using ?

Comment: Sorry this is SQL Server 2012

Comment: Throw more details...Do you have an error, or it is just that your query does nothing or not what you expect ?

Comment: I really wish you were using a FROM so you could alias that table name.

Answer (score 1):

With your original query I got a conversion error as the multiplication was treating the decimal value as an int, I guess you might have experienced the same problem.

One remedy that fixed it was to turn the factor into a decimal by adding `.0` to it.

If you want to get the number formatted with commas you can use format function like so: `FORMAT(CAST(value AS DECIMAL), 'N0')` (be sure to specify appropriate length and precision for the decimal type).

Sample test data and output from SQL Fiddle below:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05611/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE [_ParsedXML_Key_Stats] (value VARCHAR(50), NodeName VARCHAR(50));
INSERT [_ParsedXML_Key_Stats] VALUES 
('111', 'SOMETHING ELSE'),
('999', 'EBITDA'),
('47.13B', 'EBITDA'),
('1.44B', 'EBITDA'),
('1.564M', 'EBITDA');

WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
       Value, 
       CAST(LEFT([Value],LEN([Value])-1) AS DECIMAL(28,6)) AS newValue,
       RIGHT(RTRIM([Value]),1) AS c 
    FROM [_ParsedXML_Key_Stats] 
    WHERE [NodeName] = 'EBITDA'
    AND RIGHT(RTRIM([Value]),1) IN ('B','M')
) 

UPDATE cte
SET [Value] = 
CASE
  WHEN c = 'B' THEN newValue * 1000000000.0
  WHEN c = 'M' THEN newValue * 1000000.0
END;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *, FORMAT(CAST(Value AS DECIMAL(18,0)),'N0') AS formattedValue
FROM _ParsedXML_Key_Stats
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05611/1/0)**:

```
|              value |       NodeName | formattedValue |
|--------------------|----------------|----------------|
|                111 | SOMETHING ELSE |            111 |
|                999 |         EBITDA |            999 |
| 47130000000.000000 |         EBITDA | 47,130,000,000 |
|  1440000000.000000 |         EBITDA |  1,440,000,000 |
|     1564000.000000 |         EBITDA |      1,564,000 |
```

Comment: @Treyvon - This is your solution.  Adding the .0 or casting the results is a good call by jpw.  And I like the fact they're using a LEFT instead of SUBSTRING.

Comment: Thanks this is great. 2 questions for you if you don't mind: how can i modify so that '47.13B' shows up as 47,130,000,000? Currently I am losing the '3'.

Comment: Also, how can i make the ELSE statement essentially do nothing, instead of zero out what is there? When i try to change it i get "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric." thanks!

Comment: @Treyvon I've updated the query so that it only changes the correct rows. The 3 in 47,13B got truncated by the implicit conversion to decimal(18,0), (and this is why precision should always be specified - my bad). The query should work as you expect it to now.

Comment: @Treyvon If my answer provided a solution to your question, please consider marking it as accepted. :)